# PHP Split string with regex

Tags: php, regex, string

I've been trying for a while now, but never really understood Regex. How can I split this string so I get the age of the domain? Thanks.

```
<a target=_blank title='View how the website looked at this Age' href=website-history.php?archiveCreationTime=2013050316413&domain=domain.net>0 years 9 months old</a>
```

btw, the code is part of a html source.

Sorry, might be a noob question. But I've never got the time to learn Regex. And I tried with explode, but I coulden't make it get the age.

Comment: Using a DOM Parser better suit this task. I believe a good PHP one is [SimpleHTMLDOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 3):

[You shouldn't use regular expressions for parsing HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). You should use tools designed for this like [DomDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php). Here's a basic example:

```
<?php
$string = "<a target=_blank title='View how the website looked at this Age' href=website-history.php?archiveCreationTime=2013050316413&domain=domain.net>0 years 9 months old</a>";
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($string);
$anchor = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0);
echo $anchor->nodeValue;
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/XqIPJp)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [phpQuery](https://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) to do this. If you need a practical example, you can read how to [scrape anchor tags](http://kobashicomputing.com/build-an-anchor-tag-scraper). There's some relevant code there to show you how to get at the anchor tags and pull out the inner text for the anchor node.